# How to hide lines (onclick) in Seaborn scatterplot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, events, seaborn

I have a Scatterplot made with seaborn similar to this:

```
    tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
    g = sns.scatterplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="time", data=tips)
    plt.show()
```

[Resulting Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GvxF.png)

I want to be able to do legend picking like in this matplotlib example:
https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/event_handling/legend_picking.html

How do I get the individual lines to change the visibility on?

I've tried to get them via the `get_children` method, but haven't had any success.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67127873/7758804

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I dont think this anwsers my question though, as I still dont know how to get the individuals lines to set the visibility on.