# Toggle specific points on and off in python plot with tkinter

Tags: class, matplotlib, tkinter, plot, canvas

I am trying to create a plot in Tkinter, where the user is able to toggle some lines of the plot on or off, for easier comparison between lines.
Say the user have 5 plots all plotted in the same figure, i want the user to be able to toggle one plot, and make that plot invisible, so they can compare the remaning 4, and add it back in, with the same button. So lets say, the user wants to deselect cycle 10, they write 10 in the textbox below, and press the button.. It would be cooler with a simple toggle botton for each cycle.

[image]

```
class CVplotter(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self,parent, NOC,ExcelData,ActiveMass):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        self.ExcelData=ExcelData
        self.NOC = NOC
        self.NOP = len(self.NOC)
        self.ActiveMass = ActiveMass

        self.widgets()
        self.layout()
        self.plotdata()
        
    def plotdata(self):
        for j in list(self.NOC):
            print(f"dette er {j}")
            print(f"dette er = {self.NOC}")
            new_list = []
            new_list2 = []
            rest_list = []
            for i in range(100):
                temp = self.ExcelData["Cycle:Command"][self.ExcelData["Cycle:Command"] == f"{j} : {i}"].index.tolist()
                if temp:
                    new_list.append(temp[0])
                    print(f"running on cycle {j} {new_list}")
            for m in new_list:
                if self.ExcelData["Cmd Type"][m] == "CC-CVC" or self.ExcelData["Cmd Type"][m] == "CCD":
                    print("Is this slow")
                    new_list2.append(m)
                else:
                    print("or this")
                    rest_list.append(m)
            a = 0
            for n in new_list2:
                self.vmV = self.ExcelData["V(mV)"][n+1:rest_list[a]]/1000
                self.cmAh = self.ExcelData["C(mAh)"][n+1:rest_list[a]]/self.ActiveMass

                self.b.plot(self.vmV,self.cmAh)
                a += 1    

        

    def showhide(self):
        
        
        
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(6,6))
        self.b = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        
        self.b.set_title (f"Plotting Cycles{self.NOC}", fontsize=16)
        self.b.set_ylabel("Y", fontsize=14)
        self.b.set_xlabel("X", fontsize=14)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig,master = self)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
        self.canvas.draw()

        
    def widgets(self):
        self.ShowHideV = tk.IntVar()
        self.ShowHideE = ttk.Entry(self,textvariable=self.ShowHideV)    
        self.ShowHideB = ttk.Button(self,text="Show/Hide plot",command = self.showhide)
            
    def layout(self):
        
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(6,6))
        self.b = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        
        self.b.set_title (f"Plotting Cycles{self.NOC}", fontsize=16)
        self.b.set_ylabel("Y", fontsize=14)
        self.b.set_xlabel("X", fontsize=14)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig,master = self)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
        self.canvas.draw()
        
        
        
        self.ShowHideE.pack()
        self.ShowHideB.pack()
```

I am able to plot the data, and i have the buttons for it, it is basically the part where i need to write a function, which allows for this, at a button press i am lacking and it should be able to handle a user specificed number of cycles, such that it can works with 1 or 100.
I am open for suggestions, either if there is a better way of plotting it, like using seaborn or there is a method in matplotlib which allows for this (I know about the one where i can hide the entire plot, not what i want.) The difficulty lies in creating it such that the amount of plots, varies. I could create a CheckBox with a command set_visible(self.var.get()) etc. However, this will require me to know how many plots the user will create. ([How to toggle legend on and off together with respective lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67127873/how-to-toggle-legend-on-and-off-together-with-respective-lines)) This have some of the answere but not the entire answere.

TLDR:
I dont know how to let the user deside which cycles to be visble, while the amount of cycles varies depending on the user input.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31410043/hiding-lines-after-showing-a-pyplot-figure). The code works together with tkinter, I implemented it like this in a simple GUI.

```
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()

    fig, ax, leg = main()
    figure = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, root)
    figure.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='wens')

    root.mainloop()
```